# Can a Hadith naratied from Khawarij be considered authentic?

Tags: shia-sunni, uloom-al-hadith

According to Hadith sciences, how is a hadith which is narrated from Khawarij handled?

Can it be considered authentic or as soon as it is proved it is narrated from any of Khawarij , is it considered not authentic?

What is ruling about such kind of hadith according to hadith sciences?

Answer (score 3):

According to many of Hadith scholars, including Bukhari and Muslem, the Khawarij narration can be accepted as authentic hadith as long as the person is considered Muslim and known with piety and good memory.

The reason to accept Khawarij narration is that they consider sins, including lying, as act of Kufr and the person who lies, in their view, is considered to be out of Islam.

Comment: can you cite evidence for your claims

Comment: I can cite many articles but in Arabic, e.g.
http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=138847